# JPanels not showing up, kinda

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, synchronized

I am an in-school amateur making a snake game in java, it is not complete and i have run into a problem that i cant seem to fix. the first and second parts of the body show up just fine after eating the target, but after that they do not.

code that adds a body part:

```
  public void addBody(int x, int y) {
    snekBody.add(new JPanel());
    snekBody.get(snekBody.size() - 1).setBackground(new Color(new Random().nextInt(255), new Random().nextInt(255), new Random().nextInt(255)));
    snekBody.get(snekBody.size() - 1).setVisible(true);
    snekBody.get(snekBody.size() - 1).setBounds(x*score, y*score, BODY_WIDTH, BODY_HEIGHT);
    game.add(snekBody.get(this.snekBody.size() - 1));
    revalidate();
  }
}
```

code that moves the body parts(moveUp, moveDown, etc.:

```
public synchronized void moveRight(int x, int y) {
    timer++;
    while (!this.right) {
      try {
        wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    head.setBounds(x, y, 20, 20);
    xCoords.add(x);
    yCoords.add(y);
    //snekBody is an ArrayList of type JPanel
    for(int i = 0; i < snekBody.size(); i++) {
      if (i > 0) {
        snekBody.get(i).setBounds(xCoords.get(timer-(10*score)), yCoords.get(timer-(10*score))+5, BODY_WIDTH, BODY_HEIGHT);
      } else {
        snekBody.get(i).setBounds(xCoords.get(timer-10), yCoords.get(timer-10)+5, BODY_WIDTH, BODY_HEIGHT);
      }
    }
    repaint();
    notifyAll();
    revalidate();
  }
```

code that calls addBody:

```
 if (snek.up) {
          snek.addBody(snek.xCoords.get(snek.timer-20), snek.yCoords.get(snek.timer-20));
```

[the second picture is the snake when more than two targets have been eaten. the panels for the body just stop showing up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3l5V.png)
[The first picture is the snake when two targets have been eaten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXGFm.png)

Comment: Can you include a picture or better description of what isn't showing up?  Is your JPanel not showing up at all, or just part of the snake you're trying to render?

Comment: Pictures added of the snake

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the panels were showing up on top of each other, thus why i could not see them.